# .bat file does not work for R script

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to create a .bat file for an R script. I am really new to all this, so it is very possible that I make a beginners mistake.

Anyway, I have an R script called 'UCB.R', located in directory 'C:/Documents'. So I create a document in notepad called 'task.bat' containing following content:

```
"C:\Users\PiKr\Documents\version 1.0\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH 
C:\Documents\UCB.R
```

The script should give save a .txt document in my working directory, but this does not seem to work as nothing appears.

So I tried to write a much simpler R script called 'simple.R':

```
data(mtcars)
write.csv(mtcars,file="cars.csv")
```

and now the .bat file seems to successfully execute the script.

Can anyone make a suggestion to this poor soul on what might possibly be wrong? Note that the script executes perfectly when I run it through R, so the mistake is somwhere in the .bat file.

Due to privacy reasons I cannot copy the full script of UCB.R, but basically it using RSelenium to navigate towards a webpage and download some files. I also included in the beginning of the script the same as in 'Simple.R' to see if running the .bat file did anything at all, but no dataset appeared in my working directory.

Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can always create 'dummy' data. Its hard to tell. I hope someone knows

Comment: If I run an R script, I can see where things go wrong. If I try to running through the .bat file, I cannot see where things go wrong. That's the annoying part.